# Make A JPanel Follow The Cursor Just By Clicking On It

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Here's what I am trying to do, I want to make a panel follow the cursor after clicking on it, my initial idea is doing it with a drag and drop operation but the problem is the clic must be pressed for the panel to be dragged and I want the panel to be dragged just by clicking on it without keeping the clic pressed. ANY IDEAS?
Thanks guys :)

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    JComponent panDrag = new DraggableComponent();
    Icon newi = new ImageIcon("src/red.png");
    JLabel labelImage = new JLabel(newi);
    panDrag.add(labelImage);


    JPanel panneau = new JPanel();
    panneau.add(panDrag);

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(panneau);
    f.setSize(300, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }



}
class DraggableComponent extends JPanel implements DragGestureListener, DragSourceListener, MouseListener {
    DragSource dragSource;

    public DraggableComponent() {
        dragSource = new DragSource();
        dragSource.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this);
        this.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));

        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent evt) {
        Transferable t = new StringSelection("aString");
        dragSource.startDrag(evt, DragSource.DefaultCopyDrop, t, this);
    }

    public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("enters");
    }

    final JButton clickTwiceButton = new JButton();
    final JButton fireEventButton = new JButton();

    public void dragOver(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("over" + evt.getX() + "-" + evt.getY());

        this.setLocation(evt.getX() - 50, evt.getY() - 70);




    }

    public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("leaves");
    }

    public void dropActionChanged(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("changes the drag action between copy or move");
    }

    public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("finishes or cancels the drag operation");


        // Invoking later for no reason, just to simulate your code
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("sdffdf");
                clickTwiceButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(
                     fireEventButton,
                     MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 
                     1,
                     MouseEvent.BUTTON1, 
                     0, 0, 
                     1, 
                     true
                ));
            }
        });

    }


    //******************
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse clic");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse enter");

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse exit");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse press");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse release");
        //MouseEvent press = new MouseEvent(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10);
        //this.mousePressed(press );

    }
}
```

With this I can only drag the panel and make keep it visible which I need too, but I sill have to keep the clic pressed which I don't want :(

Comment: If you do not want this, then why you're using a `DragGestureEvent` in the first place?

Comment: Because I started with the basic drag and drop but can't figure out which function controls the mouse gestures  .. I don't know if I made myself clear ..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably be easier to just do you own custom listener for the dragging.

You could start with the `DragListener` found in the [Moving Windows](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) blog.

You would need to modify the code to handle the `mouseMoved(...)` event instead of the `mouseDragged(...)` event. You would probably need to add a "dragging" variable that you would toggle when ever the `mousePressed(...)` event is generated. The first click would set the dragging variable to "true" and the second click would set the variable to "false". Then the `mouseMoved(...)` code would only be executed when the variable is "true".